# Selenium command crash

Tags: python, selenium

I've written a simple crawler for data retrieval, however sometimes specific commands crash due to some other elements. For example the below command:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='abcs__123 js-tabs ']").click()
```

returns:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element <a class="abcs__123 js-tabs "> is not clickable at point (549,38) because another element <div class="header__container"> obscures it
```

How can i fix this issue? Now i use the below trick:

```
time.sleep(8)
```

but it delays my program at a fixed rate without any guarantee for the above error avoidance.

Answer (score 0):

There are several cases when this happens, so I can't know what exactly causes the issue in you specific case.
Clicking the element with JavaScript or moving to the element with Actions and then clicking on it helps in most cases.
So please try any of the following:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='abcs__123 js-tabs ']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

or

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='abcs__123 js-tabs ']")
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element ).click(element ).perform()
```

Answer (score 0):

It may not load the element when you want to find it, but there are several causes for this problem.
if your problem about time to load the element, test this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

driver = webdriver.Chrome() #or firefox
driver.get("url")
delay = 10 #sec
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//a[@class='abcs__123 js-tabs ']')))
    print ("Element loaded")
except TimeoutException:
    print ("Loading too much time")
```